# Reduces image by width first, then after max-width, proportionally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a image that have **1200 x 200px**. On center of this image I have a space with **500 x 200px** that is the main content of *full image*. On each side of this image, I have an additional content. **Note: it is on a single image.**

If the window width is reduced, then first it should consumes the additional content of the image, but cutting it, keeping image height intact. But if I reduces the window width below of the main content width (in this time, all additional content was cutted off), then now the image should be resized proportionally, affecting the height.

**My doubts:**

1. Is possible do it only with CSS?
2. If not, there are some JS library to do that?
3. If not, how I should structure the HTML, CSS and JS to do it works?

---

**It's an example banner with full width:** Note that is have a main content and two sides with additional content.

[image]

**This image below should help understand:** I tried to simulate a window width resize, on 1200 px, 1000 px and 500 px (that not affect height yet) then by 350 px (that affect and resize image proportionally).

[image]

Comment: Yes, This can be done with css only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#banner {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/csRha.png");
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #banner {
    width: 1200px;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #banner {
    background-position: 50% 0;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
  #banner {
    background-size: 240%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is possible do it only with CSS?

Yes, and you only need 1 `<div>`. Treat the image as a background image, positioned dead center with `background-position`. Then resize the `<div>` using media queries, setting widths to the designated breakpoints.

Comment: Make sense... I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a simple media query like this:

```
@media max-width: 500px {
  #your-image {
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries for adding images/elements and changing css.
As for your problem use percentages for re-sizing images.
I suggest to look up progressive enhancement and Responsive design.
Also look up view-port in case you are not using it.
Don't use VW there is not enough support yet in IE,EDGE(no support for VMAX) and Opera mini, ie8 (no support at all).